# Making Laravel Cart

Tags: ajax, laravel, session, view, cart

I'm collecting data from a form and sending to a controller

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var supplier = $('select[name="supplier"]').val();
    var reqdate = $('input[name="reqdate"]').val();
    var priority = $('input[name="priority"]:checked').val();
    if( supplier !='' && reqdate !=''){
    var Material_ID = [];
    var Material_Name = [];
    var Mat_Quantity =[];
    var Unit_Price =[];
    var Cost =[];

    $('.matid').each(function(){
        Material_ID.push($(this).text());
    });
    $('.matname').each(function(){
        Material_Name.push($(this).text());
    });
    $('.unitprice').each(function(){
        Unit_Price.push($(this).text());
    });
    $('.matqty').each(function(){
        Mat_Quantity.push($(this).text());
    });
    $('.matcost').each(function(){
        Cost.push($(this).text());
    });
    var _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        url:"{{ route('purchase.sessionstore') }}",
        method:"POST",
        data:{supplier:supplier,reqdate:reqdate,priority:priority,Material_ID:Material_ID,Material_Name:Material_Name,Unit_Price:Unit_Price,Mat_Quantity:Mat_Quantity,Cost:Cost,_token:_token},
        success:function(data){

            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

in the controller, I'm trying to put all variables into a Session

```
public function storeSessionData(Request $request){

    if($request){
        $supplier = $request->get('supplier');
        $duedate = $request->get('reqdate');
        $priority = $request->get('priority');
        $token = $request->get('_token');

        $materialid = $request->get('Material_ID');
        $materialname = $request->get('Material_Name');
        $matqty = $request->get('Mat_Quantity');
        $unitprice = $request->get('Unit_Price');
        $cost = $request->get('Cost');
        $cart[] = array($supplier, $duedate,$materialid,$priority,$materialname,$matqty,$unitprice,$cost);
        Session::set('cart', $cart);
        return $cart;
    }
}
```

I want to open a view with session data to show ordered items (just like a page to confirm cart)

What I want to do - collect data from a dynamic form and display them with a second view, on that view I will save them to database

how can I do it, please explain